# Use Keycloak`s users in own application

Tags: database, authentication, oauth-2.0, keycloak

We have several applications where we use custom implemented security and user management. Now we would probably switch to keycloak as it is a better solution.

In every app we use our User model at several places, like Product (f.e. creator_id = 1) a.s.o.
Similar question was asked here [Keycloak and spring boot rest api - user specific data stragegy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42962828/keycloak-and-spring-boot-rest-api-user-specific-data-stragegy)

My questions are:

How can I keep our User models but use keycloak for authentication and user management without migrating our users to keycloak? And how to sync the process of user registration (with Keycloak)? An useful example would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Take a look at [my answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39259607/how-to-integrate-or-make-use-of-keycloak-user-database-in-my-application) and see if it would work for you.  I've been using it for a while and it's been working well.

Comment: we will think about. thank you. but one of the points is to have a consistent state between the databases. I don`t know if we should go on with custom provider for user federation or something

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest to implement a custom **User Storage SPI** (https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_user-storage-spi) that imports the user data from your custom database into Keycloak's database on-the-fly at login-time of each user.
In front of your application you can use the appropriate Keycloak adapter and a custom filter/interceptor that converts the Keycloak specific user model (see org.keycloak.KeycloakPrincipal) to your own user model.

I did this for several customers and it works very well. With that approach the code of the protected applications usually don't need to be changed.

For user registration process simply put a link on the keycloak login page that directs the user to your current registration implementation. You will need a cutom login theme in Keycloak for that. However, you probably need that custom scheme anyway to customize the Keycloak login page to your own look & feel.

Comment: thank you for a good proposal/example. Is it possible to register the users through keycloak and then update in own database by custom SPI?

Comment: With the User Storage SPI this is not possible. You can only modify user accounts imported from an external user storage and sync back those changes.
There is the __User SPI__ which allows you to replace the whole internal UserProvider. But I would not recommend replacing that with a custom implementation. It is not documented and seems to be private (it resides in component keycloak-server-spi-private).

Comment: ok ,thank you. so another way is to create the user "after successful login"? i.e. if there is a new user who is able to login with keycloak but is not in the local storage (application), the user will be created?